# Help with Jetty crash log

Tags: jetty, solr

Greetings,

I am currently using solr as the backend behind a log aggregation and
search system my team is developing. All was well and good until I
noticed a test server crashing quite unexpectedly. We'd like to dig more
into the incident but none of us has much experience with Jetty crash
logs - not to mention that our Java is very rusty.

The crash log is visible here : http://pastebin.com/HZ92Ehcu

Could anyone help us with understanding what went wrong there ?

Also, would it be possible and/or wise to automatically restart the
server in case of such a crash ?

Thanks for your help. If you need any extra info about that case, do not
hesitate to ask !

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about java and jetty from a development point of view however I admin some apps runnning on jetty.

In general I found that one should use the sun (well oracle or whatever) java instead of the openjdk version.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

That's a JVM crash, there's not much you can do about it other than restart the instance. As cstamas said, try running your app on Oracle's JVM, it may work better for you.